# Match two dict and change keys in first if keys exists in second

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two `dict`:

```
a={'a':'A','b':'B'}
b={'a':123,'b':123}
```

I need check if keys 'a' and 'b' (two elements in example, in real code, it will be more) in `dict` b, exist in `dict` a.  If so, I should change the keys in `dict` b using values from `dict` a:

Expected result:

```
b={'A':123, 'B': 123}
```

How I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{a[k] if k in a else k: v for k, v in b.items()}
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP describes.

Comment: @cdlane Could you please elaborate on that? To me it seems it does to the extent applicable to Python, since `dict` keys cannot be replaced. Hence just assigning this code to `b` would get you exactly to the specified output (given the inputs) following the logic expressed in words in the question, without further speculation on what the code might do on some test cases that are currently not present in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it's done:

```
a={'a':'A','b':'B'}
b={'a':123,'b':123}
c = {}
for key in a.keys():
    if key in b.keys():
        c.update({a[key]:b[key]})
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP describes.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers so far ignore the question which wants the code to:

> change keys in dict in b for values from dict a

I infer that any data in `b`, for which there isn't a replacement key in `a`, should be left alone.  So walking the keys of `a` creating a new dictionary `c` won't work.  We need to modify `b` directly.  A fun way to do this is via the `pop()` method which we normally associate with lists but also works on dictionaries:

```
a = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}
b = {'a': 123, 'b': 124, 'C': 125}

for key in list(b):  # need a *copy* of old keys in b
    if key in a:
        b[a[key]] = b.pop(key)  # copy data to new key, remove old key

print(b)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
{'C': 125, 'A': 123, 'B': 124}
>
```

Comment: The order of the keys in `b` is actually changed in this answer because Python `dict`s do not support replacement. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62005797/5218354) gets you to the same dict while preserving the order of the objects from `b`. I am not sure in what way this is more fulfilling to OP question than the code from there.